# SUM a column more than once MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need help with a MySQL query that I have been battling to complete.I am sure it is not hard to figure out but I just can't see it.

I need to SUM one column again even though it has ran once and store that value and display it in a new column next to it?

This query displays 2 separate rows of records with 'fcpd' and 'CPDTotal' columns being the main part for this question.The 1st row  of records with column 'CPDTotal' has a value of 0.5 and so does the 2nd row. All I need to do is take the 0.5 + 0.5 to give me a total of 1 and show it in a new column after the execution.

```
    SELECT
    mdl_user_info_data.data,
    mdl_user.firstname, 
    mdl_user.lastname, 
    mdl_grade_grades.itemid, 
    mdl_grade_items.itemname,
    mdl_user_info_data.id,
    mdl_grade_grades.timecreated AS DATE,
    mdl_quiz.fcpd,
    SUM(mdl_quiz.fcpd) as CPDTotal
    FROM mdl_grade_grades

    INNER JOIN mdl_user ON mdl_grade_grades.userid = mdl_user.id
    INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items ON mdl_grade_grades.itemid = mdl_grade_items.id
    INNER JOIN mdl_quiz ON mdl_grade_items.itemname = mdl_quiz.name
    INNER JOIN mdl_course ON mdl_grade_items.courseid = mdl_course.id
    INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data ON mdl_user.id = mdl_user_info_data.userid


    WHERE mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 1
    AND mdl_grade_items.itemname IS NOT NULL
    AND mdl_user.annualCPDReportActive = 'Y'
    AND mdl_user.id = 1025
    AND (mdl_course.category = 27)
    GROUP BY  mdl_user.firstname, 
    mdl_user.lastname,
    mdl_user_info_data.data,
    mdl_grade_items.itemname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that in MySQL via trick -`WITH ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT
mdl_user_info_data.data,
mdl_user.firstname, 
mdl_user.lastname, 
mdl_grade_grades.itemid, 
mdl_grade_items.itemname,
mdl_user_info_data.id,
mdl_grade_grades.timecreated AS DATE,
mdl_quiz.fcpd,
SUM(mdl_quiz.fcpd) as CPDTotal
FROM mdl_grade_grades

INNER JOIN mdl_user ON mdl_grade_grades.userid = mdl_user.id
INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items ON mdl_grade_grades.itemid = mdl_grade_items.id
INNER JOIN mdl_quiz ON mdl_grade_items.itemname = mdl_quiz.name
INNER JOIN mdl_course ON mdl_grade_items.courseid = mdl_course.id
INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data ON mdl_user.id = mdl_user_info_data.userid


WHERE mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 1
AND mdl_grade_items.itemname IS NOT NULL
AND mdl_user.annualCPDReportActive = 'Y'
AND mdl_user.id = 1025
AND (mdl_course.category = 27)
GROUP BY  mdl_user.firstname, 
mdl_user.lastname,
mdl_user_info_data.data,
mdl_grade_items.itemname
WITH ROLLUP
```

this will not provide you a new column, but your result will contain corresponding summed rows after each group.

Comment: Thanks, this works however it creates 3 more NULL records and performance wise I am already in knee deep.Any suggestions on how to remove the duplicated records?

Comment: `NULL`-s will be for non-group columns. And they have very little influence to whole performance.

Comment: Awesome,I will play around with trying to remove the NULL records with COALESCE but time wise this is what I needed.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I may misunderstand it, but if the value doesn't change, you can multiply it with 2 maybe?

Comment: Thanks,I have considered this but the value always changes.

Comment: How do they change? I mean unless update, insert or something happens it will be same and there is no delay between two queries in your way. Server won't response somebody else unless it finishes your query so I am not sure but it is likely not to change.

Comment: We have an external party which will in the front end of the system(OOP PHP system), can on the fly change DB information so my queries have to built around that.I understand what you saying,I would not have posted the question if I did not cover all my resources.